# Issues with vertex() method in libGDX

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am working within the libGDX framework and I am trying to draw a simple triangle with VertexInfo objects and the vertex() method in the MeshPartBuilder interface. The code below is in the create() method and compiles fine but does not display a triangle like I would expect. If I uncomment the (// meshPart.triangle(v1, v2, v3);) line it does work and shows a triangle. I can not find any examples of this method in use. I found that within the MeshPartBuilder.java source it says "Use {@link #getAttributes} to check which values are available."

I have tried this and the result I am given is

```
[(a_position, 1, 3, 0) (a_normal, 8, 3, 12)]
```

I'm not sure what to do with that information and how it applies to using the vertex() method.

```
int attr = VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal;
ModelBuilder modelBuilder2 = new ModelBuilder();
modelBuilder2.begin();
MeshPartBuilder meshPart = modelBuilder2.part("triangle", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr, new Material( ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.CYAN)) );

VertexInfo v1 = new VertexInfo().setPos(0, 0, 0).setNor(0, 0, 1).setCol(Color.CYAN).setUV(0.5f, 0.0f);
VertexInfo v2 = new VertexInfo().setPos(5, 0, 0).setNor(0, 0, 1).setCol(Color.CYAN).setUV(0.0f, 0.0f);
VertexInfo v3 = new VertexInfo().setPos(5, 5, 0).setNor(0, 0, 1).setCol(Color.CYAN).setUV(0.0f, 0.5f);
meshPart.vertex(v1); meshPart.vertex(v2); meshPart.vertex(v3);

// meshPart.triangle(v1, v2, v3);

model2 = modelBuilder2.end();
instance2 = new ModelInstance(model2);
```

Let me know if any more information would be helpful.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Why is the vertex() method not functioning as expected? Should I not be seeing a display of a triangle on the screen or am I attempting to use this method incorrectly?

Comment: No, the *vertex* method wont result in displaying a *triangle*, not sure why you would expect that. If you want to add a triangle then just use the triangle method. The vertex method can be used to "Add a vertex" and "returns the index", to quote to docs: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/MeshPartBuilder.html#vertex-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo-

Comment: Ok, I guess I was expecting a triangle being displayed because I have three vertexes in the arrangement of a triangle added to the mesh.  Is the reason why it doesn't draw to the screen because it only adds the vertexes but doesn't render them? Or do I need to add shaders or something? What I'm trying to do is build a mesh using the VertexInfo() objects so using the triangle method wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Also I know there is the addMesh() method but I have been unsuccessful at using that as well and am liking the use of the VertexInfo() objects which the addMesh() method doesn't use.

Comment: Why would you think that using the *triangle* method to add a *triangle* is not ideal? Please carefully read this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The comment section is not the best place for asking additional questions. If you prefer that, then you can join #libgdx on IRC, see also https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Getting-Help